# ab.com/1/xx/xx.html redirected to ba.com/2/xx/xx.html use .htaccess or php

Tags: php

I want to jump ba.com/2/xx/xx.html ab.com/1/xx/xx.html  to achieve it?

php to achieve is also ok

Thank you very much

(This question does not comply with the body of our quality standards. Make sure it is fully describe the problem - including you have already tried - and use the correct syntax is written.
Chinese (Simplified)
This question does not comply with the body of our quality standards. Make sure it is fully describe the problem - including you have already tried - and use the correct syntax is written.)

Comment: Well, that's a new way to get past the quality standards.

Comment: This can be realized?

Answer (score 0):

`php` :

from `ab.com/1/xx/xx.html` to `ba.com/2/xx/xx.html`

use `header("Location: ba.com/2/xx/xx.html");` on your `ab.com/1/xx/xx.html`